# Array slice ($data,1,2) what equivalence for my case?

Tags: php, arrays

Code:

```
$data = array("vanilla", "strawberry", "mango", "peaches");
print_r(array_slice($data, 1, 2));


Output:
Array
(
[0] => strawberry
[1] => mango
)
```

in my case :

```
$data = array("vanilla", "strawberry", "mango", "peaches");
$sub_set_data = array( "strawberry", "mango");
```

the Output will be the remain array:
     `array("vanilla", "peaches");`

EDIT:

`NOT array diff it look like the minus operator 7-3 = 4 or $C = $A-$B`

python concept:

```
>>> A           = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> subset_of_A  = [6, 9, 12];
>>> set(A) - set(subset_of_A)
set([8, 10, 11, 7])
>>>
```

How Can I do for this case?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for, because `array_diff` seemingly works for your example.

Comment: I updated questions.concept's python

Comment: @IEnAk, have you tried `array_diff`? I think it does exactly what you want: returns everything in A that isn't in subset of A.

Comment: acceptable,but for my case $sub_set_data its elements are the subset of $data . All of $sub_set_data in $data.

Comment: @IEnAk: There is no "minus" operator for sets, but the difference of two sets (here represented by `array_diff()` on two arrays) is _exactly_ what you are looking for. If not, you should describe whats the matter with that.

Comment: sorry i am misunderstand Set and php array! so Php no SET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need `array_diff`

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php